# Pyspark throws JNI error when creating a SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I (try to) run pyspark on Manjaro Linux with Python2. I've create a test script to create a SparkContext instance and stop it again:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    sc.stop()
```

I launch this from a terminal with `python2 filename.py`. This has worked previously but for reasons I don't understand, this now raises the following:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 22, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext()
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 292, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/opt/apache-spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 93, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I've read on SO about others solving this problem by using Java version 8 instead of 9 or 10. However, I seem to be running version 8 already, as `archlinux-java status` outputs:

```
Available Java environments:
  java-10-openjdk
  java-8-jdk
  java-8-jre/jre
  java-8-openjdk/jre (default)
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by uninstalling `java-10-openjdk`